# Frobenius pullback of an integrable connection on a quasi-projective scheme

Tags: reference-request, arithmetic-geometry, stacks, connections, crystals

Let $X_k$ be a smooth quasi-projective scheme over a finite field $k$. Let $X_K$ be a smooth lift of $X_k$ to characteristic $0$, and let $(X_K)^{\text{an}}$ denote the rigid analytic space associated to it.

While there may not be a lift of the absolute Frobenius on $X_k$ to $(X_K)^{\text{an}}$, since $\text{Isoc}(X_k/K)$ is a stack over $X_k$ with the Zariski topology, we get a "pullback by Frobenius" functor on the category $\text{Isoc}(X_k/K)$, even though there may not be a Frobenius morphism in the category of rigid analytic spaces lifting the absolute Frobenius on $X_k$.

Trying to understand if there is a canonical way to define a Frobenius on the category of vector bundles with integrable connection on $X_K$, which I denote by $\text{VIC}(X_K)$, has led me to the following question: does the algebraic category $\text{VIC}(X_K)$ also form a stack over $X_k$ for the Zariski topology?

A reference would also be appreciated.